# Shell script error "syntax error at line 145: `<<' unmatched"

Tags: linux, shell, heredoc

This is from a shell script I modified and added to:

Trying to figure out why I'm getting this: "syntax error at line 145: `<<' unmatched".
It's from the following excerpt:

```
                    #########################################################
                    #F T P RQV F I L E S
                    #########################################################

                    cat > ${FTP_SCRIPT} <<EOF
                    open ${FTP_BOX}
                    lcd ${WORK_IN}
                    cd ..
                    quote site lrecl=4000 recfm=vb cyl pri=50 sec=50
                    put ${FINAL_FILE} ${MF_RQVFILE}
                    quit
                    EOF
```

There is no other occurrence of the 'EOF' string anywhere else in this script. I ran into something like this years ago, but of course, I can't remember what the fix is.

Comment: `EOF` needs to be not indented.

Comment: That did it. Thank You!